# A pyramid from a square

Tags: geometry, three-dimensional, construction

Given a square piece of paper. Cut it into 4 pieces that could be used to create a right angle pyramid - the 4 pieces are the faces of the pyramid.

Comment: What's the definition of a right angle pyramid?

Comment: I assume the question means a right pyramid, rather than right angled. A right pyramid has the apex directly above the centre of the base.

Comment: No. Use this definition: " A right-angled pyramid has its apex above an edge or vertex of the base. In a tetrahedron these qualifiers change based on which face is considered the base" and the requirement is - apes above a vertex.

Comment: @Moti The pyramid in our solutions is a right-angled pyramid then. If you consider any of the right-angled triangles as the base, the apex will lie above one of the vertices of the base.

Comment: I am seeking a solution where three faces are perpendicular to each other - three edges are along the cartesian axes and 4 faces (I think your solution contains a face that is not a piece of the cut)

Comment: @Moti No additional faces needed. The four faces as cut can be joined together to form a right-angled pyramid exactly as you've described.

Comment: I would challenge you to find more solutions (there is at least one more) and may be there is a general "square to pyramid" generator on which I am working as a math challenge:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you could make cuts as follows

> [image]
>  so that $a$ and $b$ are the midpoints of the sides of the square.
>  Then, the three triangles surrounding the central triangle can be folded up along their adjoining edges to create a pyramid.

Comment: I edited the puzzle to reflect the requirement for a right angle pyramid. Hope I am not disappointing you since you have a nice solution.

Comment: I think your solution uses an additional face that is not part of the cuts.

Comment: @Moti There are four triangles in the picture. Those are the four faces, why would I need another one?

Comment: @Moti, if we use the small triangle as the base, we could label the coordinates of this pyramid in three-space as (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,2). This is exactly what you've described in your comment.

Comment: You are right and I am accepting your solution

Answer (score 3):

How about this cut? (With Region A as the base of the pyramid)

> [image]

Comment: Seems to be exactly the same as the answer that preceded yours by a few minutes.

Comment: It is, I was putting together the diagram and as I was posting I was notified the other solution was posted. I'm fairly certain this is a unique solution anyway.

Comment: There is another solution for a right angle pyramid - see edited puzzle.

Comment: See also other comments - your solution is of 5 faces pyramid.